# Phantom: WalletSendTransactionError: Something went wrong nextjs

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, phantom, send-transaction, nextjs

Code works in dev version

[image: in dev version result]

In production:
Error description: Phantom - RPC Error: Something went wrong. {code: -32603, message: 'Something went wrong.'}

[image: Phantom - RPC Error: Something went wrong. in production]

[image: error]

---

In server side:

```
const { blockhash } = await (connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized'))
const transaction = new web3.Transaction({
  recentBlockhash: blockhash,
  feePayer: nftReciver,
})

const reference = web3.Keypair.generate().publicKey
  
const my_token_account = await splToken.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection, 
  payer = myKeypair, 
  mint = new web3.PublicKey(usdc.token), 
  owner = myKeypair.publicKey, 
  commitment = 'finalized', 
  allowOwnerOffCurve = false, 
  confirmOptions = null,
  programId = splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, 
  associatedTokenProgramId = splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
)

const reciver_token_account = await splToken.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection, 
  payer = myKeypair, 
  mint = new web3.PublicKey(usdc.token), 
  owner = nftReciver, 
  commitment = 'finalized', 
  allowOwnerOffCurve = false, 
  confirmOptions = null, 
  programId = splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, 
  associatedTokenProgramId = splToken.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
);

const transferInstruction = splToken.createTransferCheckedInstruction(
  source = my_token_account.address, // source
  mint = new web3.PublicKey(usdc.token), 
  destination = reciver_token_account.address, // dest
  owner = myKeypair.publicKey,
  BigInt(Math.floor((amount + bonus) * (10 **usdc?.decimals))),
  decimals = usdc.decimals,
  multiSigners = [],
  programId = splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
)

transferInstruction.keys.push({
  pubkey: new web3.PublicKey(reference),
  isSigner: false,
  isWritable: false,
})

transaction.add(transferInstruction)
transaction.sign(myKeypair)
const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize({ requireAllSignatures: false })
```

In client side:

```
import { useConnection, useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react'

const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet()
const { connection } = useConnection()

...

const transaction = Transaction.from(Buffer.from(res.transaction, 'base64'))
await sendTransaction(transaction, connection)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

File: `next.config.js` 
Remove: `swcMinify: true`

It works for me